# binary addition

Tags: arithmetic, binary

Can any direct me to any resources online that teach how to approach binary addition such as this/ working with more complex binary arithmetic?  I know the basics of binary addition and carrying the one over in simple problems, but I get very confused in larger problems such as this and I don't really understand what to do when there are more than 3 ones in a column. Or, if anyone can provide any sort of explanation.

Binary addition:

```
10111.011
 1001.001
11011.101
 1101.111
 1011.010
```

Comment: In binary you only have $0$ and $1$ available to you and nothing else. so $1+1+1=(1+1)+1=0+1=1$, and like that.

Comment: He is not referring to $(\mathbb{Z}_2,+)$ but is instead referring to addition in base2, so in his context $1+1+1 = 11$ instead of $1$.  But yea, adding multiple numbers simultaneously works the same in base2 as it does in base10.  If you added $39+47+15$ together, for the ones column you'll have a total of $21$ so you can leave the ones' $1$ and carry the tens' $2$.  If you had added enough numbers to have all of the ones' column adding to $538$ then you might carry the "tens' $53$" instead, even though its not a one digit number.

Comment: Three ones in binary will work in pretty much the same way as something like... 13 9's in decimal. 9x13 would be 117, so you carry the 1 to the next column and another 1 to the next column after that.

Similarly: 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 in binary would make 110, you would just carry over more than one column.

Answer (score 1):

I give an explanation for an example.

```
    011
    001
    101
    111
_______________
```

**Last column**:

1+1+1+1=2+2

This means the result is **0** and you carry over 1 for each 2, thus in total 2.

**second column:**

1+1=2 plus the carry over from the last column=2+2

This means the result is **0** and you carry over 1 for each 2, thus in total 2

**First column:**

1+1 plus the carry over from the second column=2+2

This means the result is **0** and you carry over 1 for each 2, thus in total 2

**Next dual place** (left from the first column):

The carry over from the first column (2) gives **0** and and the carry over is 1.

**Next dual place** (2 columns left from the first column):

Just **1**.

In total the number is **$10000_2=16_{10}$**

**Edit**:

```
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
_______________
```

The sum is 6. You drop 0. And carry over 6/2=3=2+**1**. In the next column you drop **1** and carry over 1 because of  the 2. Thus you get $110_2=6_{10}$

Comment: For what is the downvoting ? Please leave a comment.

Comment: ok, so I understand what to do with 4's in a column now, but what about the case when there are 5 1's in a column? Do I drop a one down and then carry over 2 ones?  And what about the case of 6 ones and 7 ones?

Comment: In the case of 5 ones you are right. And then in the next column you drop 0 down and carry over 1. In total $101_2=5_{10}$. For the case of 6 ones I will make an edit.

Comment: (+1)Good answer, not sure why the downvote.